# working with testDatasource function in Grafana Datasource plugin

Tags: grafana

I am building a Grafana data source plugin that I need to update the pluginOptions/instanceSettings in the testDatasource function in the Datasource class.

Is there any way I can implement this feature?

[Working with testDatasource in DataSource class for plugin options](https://community.grafana.com/t/working-with-testdatasource-in-datasource-class-for-plugin-options/42261)

Thank you.

Comment: Have you made an attempt at a solution? If so, can you please post what you have tried.

Comment: I can't update the instanceSettings object in testDatasource function.